# How to create a UITableViewCell as those in Contacts app?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

How do you replicate a cell such as the one sin the Contacts detail view? The have a "prefix" static text in blue followed (on the same line) by an editable text in black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are just using a custom tableviewcell with a blue label for prefix, black label for text and a custom background image. The background image will be different depending on where it is located in a group:

- only cell in a group (rounded top and bottom)
- first cell in a multi-cell group (rounded on top, flat on
  bottom)
- middle cell in a mult-cell group (flat on top and bottom)
- last cell in a multi-cell group (rounded on bottom, flat on top)